# Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required in Laravel with Mailtrap.io

Tags: laravel

I looked through the answers on SO but nothing seems to work. The weird thing is that I have the *exact same* `.env` variables and `config/mail.php` in another local project, and in that project everything works as expected.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=my_mailtrap_username
MAIL_PASSWORD= my_mailtrap_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example
```

In `config/mail.php` I have

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

I know that `MAIL_HOST` has a different fallback vs the host that I have specified in my `.env`, but the second value is the fallback and it should just be using that from my `.env` file. Again, this works fine in an other local project.

I ran:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan queue:restart
```

Comment: Load up `php artisan tinker`, then do `config('mail')` and make sure the values are what they should be.

Comment: That's a great pointer! Interestingly, `driver`, `host` and `port` are coming through correctly but `encryption`, `username` and `password` are not. Now I'm even more confused :-)

Comment: Are these values in `config/mail.php` configured to pull from `.env` for that driver?

Comment: Yep, just added this to the question. I'm so puzzled because the contents of these files (`config/mail` and `.env`) are 1:1 the same in two local projects and in the other project everything works. So I'm guessing it has to do with caching, but `php artisan config:cache` should fix that.

Comment: If I change the port, run `php artisan config:clear` and then `config('mail')` in tinker the port is not updated. So old values are used somehow and none of it is getting updated.

Comment: If I look at `bootstrap/cache/config.php` then: after running `php artisan config:clear` it's removed as expected, but after running `php artisan config:cache` I can see that it's not pulling updated `.env` variables. This is really weird. It seems my only option is defining the variables directly in `config/mail.php`.

Comment: sounds like there is a really simple issue, like a misnamed `.env` file. The "old" values dont come out of nowhere.

Comment: try to restart your webserver and see what you get (wamp, xampp), whatever,

Comment: I run my projects locally with valet and have done `valet restart`, the issue is still there. @Flame it looks like it, although other variables in the same file are picked up, also when I change them so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

All the facepalm memes in the world can not describe how I feel right now.

I had all the MAIL variables in the .env file declared AGAIN further down in the file, so they got overwritten... I also still had my `.env.example` file but I don't think that caused the issue.

Comment: i foresaw this facepalm moment